# Is there a way to automatically use sudo whenever I get "Permission denied"?

Tags: sudo

Is there a way to automatically use `sudo` whenever I get "Permission denied"?

I don't want to become superuser, since I still want to be asked for the password in such cases. I just don't want to write `sudo` in front of everything.